# Activate conda environment in upstart configuration file

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, anaconda, gunicorn, conda, upstart

I have a digital ocean droplet running a django project through gunicorn on ubuntu. A conda environment to manages the python dependencies.

I can log in, run `source activate py35`, `cd` into the django project and run `gunicorn django.wsgi -w 2 -t 360`, and have everything start without a problem.

I've tried modifying the upstart script that was created by digital ocean when the droplet was created to:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn limit 10 2

setuid my_username
setgid my_username
chdir /home/my_username/django


script
    exec source activate py35
    exec gunicorn django.wsgi -w 2 -t 360
end script
```

However, the workers fail to start, and in the logs the errors are due to the project attempting to run on the standard install of python, rather than the conda env. How do I activate the conda environment in an upstart configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

upstart uses /bin/sh while source needs to be executed with /bin/bash

try this:

```
script
/bin/bash <<EOT
     source activate py35 && gunicorn django.wsgi -w 2 -t 360
EOT
end script
```